# Replace ArrayList Values with new String Values

Tags: java, android, arraylist

i have a arraylist called arrstatus which has a set of Numeric values stored dynamically.
I have to Replace those Numeric Values with Unique String values.
I tried various methods it doesnt seem to be working 
i tries Set method, didnt work,

```
// int[] flags = new int[arrstatus_old.size()];

int [] c =  new int [arrtaskid.size()];
Toast.makeText(MyTask.this, "C:"+c, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

     for(int j=1;j<= c.length;j++)
     {

        if(arrstatus.get(j).equals("1"))
         {
             arrstatus_old.set(j, "Saved");
         }
        else if(arrstatus.get(j).equals("2"))
        {
            arrstatus_old.set(j, "Assigned");
        }
        else if(arrstatus.get(j).equals("3"))
        {
            arrstatus_old.set(j, "Accepted");
        }
        else if(arrstatus.get(j).equals("4"))
        {
            arrstatus_old.set(j, "Rejected");
        }

     }
```

I am not getting the size of the arrastutus, it says 0 
and hence no values are getting replaced,
any better idea to replace the value.?

Comment: `j<= c.length` This might cause `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun - Not might.. it will (unless he gets some other exception before that..) :P

Comment: Ya just change it to `j <= c.length - 1`

Comment: @TheLostMind Depends on the `if`s on the last index..

Comment: @Sanj FYI array index starts from `0`

Comment: i had set j= 0 initially and j<c.length , it should array out of bound even then

Comment: @sanj Take a look at answer below

Comment: @sanj none of your if condition evaluates to true. Please verify your contents in arraylist or paste your arraylist  (in your case arrstatus and arrstatus_old) contents here.

Comment: the arraylist arrstatus consists values like 3,2,1,4,1,1 etc , the control does not go inside the condition check , that is in if check 1 or 2 or 3 so on , i dont understand the problem

Answer (score 1):

Your `ArrayList` in which `1` i.e. `numbers` are stored should store numbers in `String` format.

Your arrayList should be like `ArrayList<String>`

```
        ArrayList<String> arrstatus = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrstatus.add("1");
        arrstatus.add("2");
        arrstatus.add("3");
```

As you are checking in arraylist using `equals` you'll have add numbers as a String.

```
if (arrstatus.get(i).equals("1")) {
    arrstatus.set(i, "Saved");
}if (arrstatus.get(i).equals("2")) {
    arrstatus.set(i, "Assigned");
}if (arrstatus.get(i).equals("3")) {
    arrstatus.set(i, "Accepted");
}
```

and so on...

Comment: i have  ArrayList<String> arrstatus = new ArrayList<String>(); and the values are dynamically stored from server.

Comment: @sanj Problem is with your arraylist to which you want to change. In order to change the element, it must contain the element that you are checking (In condition).

Comment: @JavaLearner ArrayList.add(index, element) will shift the existing element the "index" position to right.. Refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add%28int,%20E%29       he wants to replace the existing element

Comment: @Jayaprasad I have edited my answer. It was written by mistake. Will u please remove your downvote?

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> arrstatus = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrstatus.add("1");
        arrstatus.add("2");
        arrstatus.add("3");
arrstatus.add("4");

for(int j=0;j< c.length;j++)
     {

        if(arrstatus.get(j).equals("1"))
         {
             arrstatus_old.set(j, "Saved");
         }
        else if(arrstatus.get(j).equals("2"))
        {
            arrstatus_old.set(j, "Assigned");
        }
        else if(arrstatus.get(j).equals("3"))
        {
            arrstatus_old.set(j, "Accepted");
        }
        else if(arrstatus.get(j).equals("4"))
        {
            arrstatus_old.set(j, "Rejected");
        }

     }
```